# Multi-Monitor Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-8

Since going back to school (for my M.S. I went from SysAdmin to part-time/consultant), I'm frequently working from my home office, and I find myself often using remote desktop to work on specific systems.

My system is running Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64 and is fully updated. I have 4 monitors, each running at 1920x1080 arranged side-by-side. It looks something like this:

[ 4 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]

Using the Windows RDP client, I'm trying to connect to a Windows 7 Professional SP1 x64 machine, also fully updated. I can connect fine, but I need to get the connection to show TWO MONITORS, FULLSCREEN on TWO of my monitors.

I think I've tried about every option I've come across in my search. the multi-monitor checkbox, /span, /multimon, screen mode id:i:2, etc., with no luck. Any help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multiple-monitors support the remote system has to be Windows 7 Ultimate or Windows 7 Enterprise.

See answer to "Which editions of Windows 7 include multiple-monitor support for Remote Desktop Connection?" at [Remote Desktop Connection: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/remote-desktop-connection-faq#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: You are correct - I had read this, but I was thinking it applied to the local system, not the remote system. Thank you!

Comment: Linked page was updated August 2016 and no longer contains the referenced content.